# How to provide application class using hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am using a library that needs the Application class (not the application context) that I am using to work

its builder is something like `Library.Builder.setApplication(app).setParameters(...).build()`

is there a way to use the currently created Application in Hilt? @ApplicationContext obviously does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but maybe you can cast Application Context to Application class. I had similar problem when I needed Activity instance in provides method. I cast Activity Context from Hilt annotations and it works.

Comment: I marked your reply as the correct one cause it does indeed work, you can cast @ApplicationContext to your custom application, but just as a note, you can pass in the provides method the app:Application arguement, cause it seems that Hilt always creates that one by default and it does not need any annotations for it

Answer (score -1):

Simply inject the Application class:

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(
    private val application: Application,
)
```